# evaluating mysql NULL with = operator

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I have following `Qt/C++` class method:

```
bool UeOrdersModel::ueSlotRefreshOrdersData(const QString& userId,
                                            const QString& placeId,
                                            const QString& customerId)
{
    bool result=false;
    bool connected=false;
    bool customerIdEmpty=customerId.isEmpty()||customerId.isNull();

    this->ueSetUserId(userId);
    this->ueSetPlaceId(placeId);
    if(this->ueDatabase().isOpen())
    {
        connected=true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(this->ueConnectToDatabase())
        {
            connected=this->ueDatabase().open();
        }   // if
    }   // if

    if(connected)
    {
        this->setQuery(UePosDatabase::UeSqlQueries::UeViewOrders::SQL_QUERY_GET_ORDERS_FILTERED_BY_USERID_PLACEID_CUSTOMER_ID.arg(userId)
                                                                                                                             .arg(placeId)
                                                                                                                             .arg(customerIdEmpty?QString(QString::null):customerId),
                       this->ueDatabase());

        if(this->query().lastError().isValid())
        {
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                     << this->query().lastError().text();
        }
        else
        {
            this->ueUpdateTotalAmounts(userId,
                                       placeId,
                                       customerId);
            result=true;
        }   // if
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                 << this->lastError().text();
    }   // if

    return result;
}   // ueSlotRefreshOrdersData
```

which basically executes following `mysql` query:

```
static const QString SQL_QUERY_GET_ORDERS_FILTERED_BY_USERID_PLACEID_CUSTOMER_ID=  
"SELECT ORDERS.USER_ID, PEOPLE.NAME, PLACE_ID, PLACES.NAME, PRODUCT_ID, "
"PRODUCTS.IMAGE, PRODUCTS.NAME, PRODUCTS.PRICESELL, TAXES.RATE, ORDERS.PRODUCT_QUANTITY, ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID "
"FROM ORDERS "
"JOIN PEOPLE ON ORDERS.USER_ID=PEOPLE.ID "
"JOIN PRODUCTS ON ORDERS.PRODUCT_ID=PRODUCTS.ID "
"JOIN PLACES ON ORDERS.PLACE_ID=PLACES.ID "
"JOIN TAXCATEGORIES ON PRODUCTS.TAXCAT=TAXCATEGORIES.ID "
"JOIN TAXES ON TAXCATEGORIES.ID=TAXES.ID "
"WHERE ORDERS.USER_ID=\"%1\" AND ORDERS.PLACE_ID=\"%2\" AND CUSTOMER_ID=\"%3\"";
```

Now, if method's third parameter, **customerId**, is empty, I must evaluate upper `mysql` statement with `CUSTOMER IS NULL`, I am aware of that. But, is it possible to evaluate `mysql NULL` value using `=` operator, like in my case?

Comment: This is not an answere to your question, but you should not set parameters in a query using `QString::arg`, since thats a dangerous canidate for sql-injections!!! Please check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values to read how to do it properly.